# Border Shadow React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am currently working on a react native app and want border shadows on my borders 
Any suggestions how to implement it?
I have tried shadow props of the View component but it doesn't seem to work.

And also I want some gradient background color.Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

You have to give elevation prop to View

```
<View elevation={5} style={styles.container}>
 <Text>Hello World !</Text>
</View>
```

styles can be added like this:

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({

 container:{
    padding:20,
    backgroundColor:'#d9d9d9',
    shadowColor: "#000000",
    shadowOpacity: 0.8,
    shadowRadius: 2,
    shadowOffset: {
      height: 1,
      width: 1
    }
   },
 })
```

Comment: in typescript there is no elevation attribute declared. Any idea to remove the error ? In fact you could put directly the elevation in the styles.

Answer (score 4):

you could simply use elevation like below:

`<View elevation={5}>
</View>`

Comment: elevation only works on android. For ios you need to add following properties as well with elevation:

 shadowOpacity: 0.8,
    shadowRadius: 2,
    shadowOffset: {
      height: 1,
      width: 1
    }

Answer (score 3):

I recommend using [this tool.](https://ethercreative.github.io/react-native-shadow-generator/) It shows you what the shadows will look like and gives you code you can just copy.

Answer (score 0):

to add shadow you can use [react-native-shadow](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-shadow) and for gradient [react-native-linear-gradient](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-linear-gradient)

Comment: It seems that [react-native-shadow-2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-shadow-2) has now more features and better maintenance

Answer (score 0):

1.For gradient colors use [expo-linear-gradient](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/linear-gradient/)
2.To add shadow use the elevation option in View.

```
<View elevation={5}>
{component}
</VIew>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can only use inbuilt shadow props in ios app only. For android, you can use **{elevation:2}** method to experience a shadow effect on your component but you can't be able to customize the shadow(color, offset etc.) like in ios.

Like this -

Comment: Seems your missing the example you intended to provide.